# System.Threading.Thread replacement in windows store apps

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, windows-store-apps

Is it right that 'System.Threading.Thread' douesn't exist in Windows Store Apps? And if it is, what is the replacement (I want to run a function in the background so the UI douesn't freez while calculating something).
Language is C# and XAML for the UI.

Comment: That works. I think I should practise to Google better, because I really didn't found anything there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) or [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx)

```
private void BackgroundWork() { ... }

public async Task DoUsefulWorkAsync()
{
    // Do useful work
    // Start Background Job
    Task backgroundWorkTask = Task.Run(() => BackgroundWork());

    // Do more useful work

    // Wait async for BackgroundWork to complete
    // It won't block the UI thread that we're running on
    await backgroundWorkTask;
}
```